# Build a webpage by Django, functions don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Here's my HTML code:

```
<span>
<button onclick="indexOBJ.clear();return false;" class="resetButton">清空</button>
</span>
```

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
var indexOBJ = {
    clear: function () {
        $('#devSvnURL').val('');
        $('#devVersion').val('');
        $('#testExampleUrl').val('');
        $('#testReportDemoUrl').val('');
        $('#resultLocation').val('');
        $('#username').val('');
        $('#userpwd').val('');
        $('#commitTextArea').val('');
        $('#note').val('');
    }
};

function clearAA() {
    alert()
}
```

It works fine. **However** when I change my HTML code to:

```
<span>
    <button onclick="clearAA();return false;" class="resetButton">清空</button>
</span>
```

Then, the function named `clearAA()` will never be called. I don't know why. *Please* tell me the reason. Thanks a lot.

Environment: `Django 2.0.2 jquery-3.3.1.js`

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with Django at all. Or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said in the question response, this is not a problem from django o jquery. Check in the developer tools if there is some warning or error when you click the button. If not, set a breakpoint in the function you want to call and check if enter in it.

I recommend you to use chrome developer tools.